# Convert int to hex in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, hex

I have to call a binary several times with a different argument in a shell script.
For example i have to call the binary "set" with the arguments:

set 0x00
set 0x01
set 0x02
...
set 0x60

Is it possible to do that with a loop in the shell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `%x` format to the `printf` command to do the conversion, as in `printf 0x%x num`. To pass the converted value as argument to another command, use the `$(...)` executive quotes:

```
$ i=8
$ while [ $i -lt 16 ]; do
> echo $(printf 0x%x $i)
> i=$(expr $i + 1)
> done
0x8
0x9
0xa
0xb
0xc
0xd
0xe
0xf
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, but I want to call a binary with this output as argument, not just printing the values.

Comment: @osiris81 `echo` is just an example! Substitute it with any other command of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf "0x%X" $decimal` in whatever loop you need.